# Are there built in layer controls for the Android Map?

Tags: android, dictionary

I see how easy it is to add the zoom controls. (using mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true)), and also see how easy it is to enable a particular Map layer (mapView.setTraffic(true)).

I would like to supply controls for the user to be able to show\hide the various layers interactively.

It doesn't look like the Android Map API supplies built in standard controls for layers.

I know I can create my own custom button controls, but would love to use something that is embedded already for this functionality.

Can anyone confirm that standard layer controls don't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It doesn't look like the Android Map API supplies built in standard controls for layers.

Correct. For starters, all layers are shown all the time, unless you manually remove them. `MapView` has no concept of layers being displayed or hidden -- they are always displayed.

> Can anyone confirm that standard layer controls don't exist?

I can confirm that standard layer controls do not exist.